# How to style a clicked button in CSS

Tags: html, css

I looked at W3 schools website [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_buttons.asp) which explained styling buttons with CSS. I need to specify a button style when it is clicked. What is the pseudo-class selector for this? e.g. the hover button is:

```
.button:hover{ 
}
```

Comment: w3schools is **not** the W3C

Comment: Take a look at [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).

Comment: :focus is not equivalent to click, you can have focus after click

Comment: use `:active` pseudo selector

Comment: `:active` is what you're searching for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This button will appear yellow initially. On hover it will turn orange. When you click it, it will turn red. I used :hover and :focus to adapt the style.
(The :active  selector is usually used of links (i.e. `<a>` tags))

```css
button{
  background-color:yellow;
}

button:hover{background-color:orange;}

button:focus{background-color:red;}

a {
  color: orange;
}

a.button{
  color:green;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

a:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>
Hover and Click!
</button>
<br><br>

<a href="#">Hello</a><br><br>
<a class="button" href="#">Bye</a>
```

Comment: :active is usually used of links (i.e. <a> tags)

Comment: Since some common libraries commonly and in my opinion poorly use `.button` for anchor links styled as buttons (I am looking at you bootstrap) and the OP has `.button` in the example perhaps expand this to include an anchor section with the `:active`? i.e. if they want a button they should use `<button></button>` but that is not YOUR fault :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I actually didn't notice that in the question, well pointed out , but indeed why not use a button tag if a button is desired ? I'll edit the answer to include a link with class button....

Comment: As per Mozilla documentation, one should use :active for button as well. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

Comment: One must use `active` instead of `focus`. Focus remains after button is depressed, active is only while mouse is down.

Answer (score 40):

If you just want the button to have different styling while the mouse is pressed you can use the `:active` pseudo class.

```
.button:active {
}
```

If on the other hand you want the style to stay after clicking you will have to use javascript.

Answer (score 27):

There are three states of button

- Normal : You can select like this `button`
- Hover :  You can select like this `button:hover`
- Pressed/Clicked : You can select like this `button:active`

**Normal:**

```
.button
 {
     //your css
 }
```

**Active**

```
 .button:active
{
        //your css
}
```

**Hover**

```
 .button:hover
{
        //your css
}
```

**SNIPPET:**

Use `:active` to style the active state of button.

```css
button:active{
   background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, there is no :click pseudo selector. If you want to change styling on click, you should use Jquery/Javascript. It certainly is better than the "hack" for pure HTML / CSS. But if you insist...

```css
input {
display: none;
}
span {
padding: 20px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
input:checked + span {
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <label for="input">
  <input id="input" type="radio" />
  <span>NO JS styling</span>
  </label>
```

Or, if you prefer, you can toggle the styling:

```css
input {
display: none;
}
span {
padding: 20px;
font-family: sans-serif;
}
input:checked + span {
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <label for="input">
  <input id="input" type="checkbox" />
  <span>NO JS styling</span>
  </label>
```

Comment: Why checkbox and radio types? not buttons in my mind.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss You don't understand, if you ran the code snippets, maybe you would. The checkboxes are hidden, but you can take advantage of the :checked pseudo selector, which you must have the checkbox input to use. Like I mentioned in the post, this is a "hack". However, there are no other pure CSS/HTML alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

button:hover is just when you move the cursor over the button.
Try **button:active** instead...will work for other elements as well

```html
button:active{
  color: red;
}
```