# How can i change font color for a snapchat login button after click on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sdk, snapchat

I use the official login button example from [snapchat kit](https://kit.snapchat.com/docs/login-kit-web)

After clicking on the login button, the span element with text is deleted.

What should I change in my code to see span text even after clicking on the login button?

My code example is here [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-sunset-ge655?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: hi, you can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263892/how-to-style-a-clicked-button-in-css
basically just play with css and use `<a` or `<button` element

Comment: its not a css thing. Span element with text is deleted after button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this with ::before element

```
.snapchat-login-button button {
  animation: none;

  &::before {
    content: "Button text is here"
  }
}

.snapchat-login-button span {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```