# How to change button style on click in react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a a toggle button to which I want to add my own styling, I want the button to change color when it has been selected, but the problem with current code is that when the button is being pressed the color changes to desired result but as soon as I release my click, the button color goes back to its default styling. Can someone please help me with this

My React Component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ToggleButton from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButton';
import ToggleButtonGroup from 'react-bootstrap/ToggleButtonGroup';
import '../styles/components/_LoanType.scss';

const LoanType:React.VFC = () => {
    const [selectedButton, setSelectedButtonValue] = useState<string>('fixedRateLoan');
    const handleChange = (value:string) => {
        selectedButton(value);
    }

    return (
        <div className="loan-type">
            <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="radio" value={selectedButton} onChange={handleChange} >
                <ToggleButton value={'frl'}>1</ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton value={'vrl'}>2</ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton value={'spl'}>3</ToggleButton>
            </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </div>
    );
}

export default LoanType;
```

My scss file:

```
.pkg .calc {
    .ci .lts{
        .loan-type {
            .btn-group{
         

   display: flex;
            .btn-primary{
                text-align: center;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                color: #656565;
                font-weight: 900;
                &:active{
                    color: #ffffff;
                    background-color: #656565;
                }
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Seems like it is hacky to do it only with only css. Maybe try to add a click handler which adds a new style which changes its colour.

I suppose you already checked existing discussions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263892/how-to-style-a-clicked-button-in-css

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are some errors in your component.

In the change handler, you're calling the current state as a function, instead of the function that updates the state.

```
const handleChange = (value:string) => {
    selectedButton(value);
}
```

Should be

```
const handleChange = (value:string) => {
    setSelectedButtonValue(value);
}
```

**Secondly**, the documentation for `<ToggleButton>` states that an **id** is required for button clicks to toggle input. So you should add this to the buttons, e.g.

```
<ToggleButton id="frl" value={"frl"}>
  1
</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton id="vrl" value={"vrl"}>
  2
</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton id="spl" value={"spl"}>
  3
</ToggleButton>
```

You're also initializing the state with a value that is not an option. Perhaps this should be set to either frl, vrl or spl?

```
useState<string>('frl');
```

Hope this helps!